# Link / use external library in QtCreator

Tags: c++, c, qt

With mingw's Msys tool I've successfully build the opus-codec from [source 1.1.tar.gz](https://www.opus-codec.org/downloads/). The build produced some files, amongst which are `libopus.a` and `libopus-0.dll`. Now I want to try the [trivial-example.c](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/deps/opus/+/25c2f620b6de0f47a9d7e6e7859c035b31031122/doc/trivial_example.c) in QtCreator. I added the lib to my `.pro`-file and included `opus.h` in my main file. The compiler complains that it can't find the headers that are included in `opus.h` Shouldn't these be included within the lib? How do I need to setup my application to run the "trivial-example"?

My folder structure is:

- main.cpp
- opus_lib_test.pro
- opus_lib_test.pro.user
- include [folder]

  - opus.h   (from the source include folder)
- libs [folder]

  - libopus.a
  - libopus-0.dll

My `.pro`-file looks like

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = opus_lib_test
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include
LIBS += -L"C:/Qt/Qt5.2.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/opus_lib_test/libs/" -llibopus
SOURCES += main.cpp
HEADERS += include/opus.h
```

and my `main.cpp` is here:

```
//#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "opus.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    //    return a.exec();

    // ----------------------------- trivial_example.c

    char *inFile;
    FILE *fin;
    char *outFile;
    FILE *fout;
    opus_int16 in[FRAME_SIZE*CHANNELS];
    opus_int16 out[MAX_FRAME_SIZE*CHANNELS];
    unsigned char cbits[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];
    int nbBytes;
    /*Holds the state of the encoder and decoder */
    OpusEncoder *encoder;
    OpusDecoder *decoder;
    int err;
    if (argc != 3)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "usage: trivial_example input.pcm output.pcm\n");
       fprintf(stderr, "input and output are 16-bit little-endian raw files\n");
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    /*Create a new encoder state */
    encoder = opus_encoder_create(SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNELS, APPLICATION, &err);
    if (err<0)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "failed to create an encoder: %s\n", opus_strerror(err));
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    /* Set the desired bit-rate. You can also set other parameters if needed.
       The Opus library is designed to have good defaults, so only set
       parameters you know you need. Doing otherwise is likely to result
       in worse quality, but better. */
    err = opus_encoder_ctl(encoder, OPUS_SET_BITRATE(BITRATE));
    if (err<0)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "failed to set bitrate: %s\n", opus_strerror(err));
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    inFile = argv[1];
    fin = fopen(inFile, "r");
    if (fin==NULL)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    /* Create a new decoder state. */
    decoder = opus_decoder_create(SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNELS, &err);
    if (err<0)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "failed to create decoder: %s\n", opus_strerror(err));
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    outFile = argv[2];
    fout = fopen(outFile, "w");
    if (fout==NULL)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    while (1)
    {
       int i;
       unsigned char pcm_bytes[MAX_FRAME_SIZE*CHANNELS*2];
       int frame_size;
       /* Read a 16 bits/sample audio frame. */
       fread(pcm_bytes, sizeof(short)*CHANNELS, FRAME_SIZE, fin);
       if (feof(fin))
          break;
       /* Convert from little-endian ordering. */
       for (i=0;i<CHANNELS*FRAME_SIZE;i++)
          in[i]=pcm_bytes[2*i+1]<<8|pcm_bytes[2*i];
       /* Encode the frame. */
       nbBytes = opus_encode(encoder, in, FRAME_SIZE, cbits, MAX_PACKET_SIZE);
       if (nbBytes<0)
       {
          fprintf(stderr, "encode failed: %s\n", opus_strerror(nbBytes));
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       /* Decode the data. In this example, frame_size will be constant because
          the encoder is using a constant frame size. However, that may not
          be the case for all encoders, so the decoder must always check
          the frame size returned. */
       frame_size = opus_decode(decoder, cbits, nbBytes, out, MAX_FRAME_SIZE, 0);
       if (frame_size<0)
       {
          fprintf(stderr, "decoder failed: %s\n", opus_strerror(err));
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       /* Convert to little-endian ordering. */
       for(i=0;i<CHANNELS*frame_size;i++)
       {
          pcm_bytes[2*i]=out[i]&0xFF;
          pcm_bytes[2*i+1]=(out[i]>>8)&0xFF;
       }
       /* Write the decoded audio to file. */
       fwrite(pcm_bytes, sizeof(short), frame_size*CHANNELS, fout);
    }
    /*Destroy the encoder state*/
    opus_encoder_destroy(encoder);
    opus_decoder_destroy(decoder);
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The header files referenced in `opus.h`:

```
#include "opus_types.h"
#include "opus_defines.h"
```

They are both from source include folder, the same as `opus.h`. I think your problem will be solved if you copy all .h files (5 including `opus.h`) from source include folder into include [folder] in your folder structure.

Header files are not included in lib, only cpp files are included. You need to specify header files separately.